# Four Romex cables, but two neutral wires cut?

Tags: electrical

Noticed some outlets weren't working. Opened up the first one and found four Romex cables with hot wires attached, but two of the neutral wires were cut and disconnected.

Pictured below is the very next outlet, which has three Romex cables with hot wires connected, but one neutral wire cut and disconnected.[image]

Is there a standard reason for doing something like that?

Update: it looks like maybe the old outlets were half-switched? Found one, and hot tab was broken, but neutral was not[image][image]

Comment: Did the outlets stop working or did you just move in and find they don’t work?

Comment: I actually can't say for sure, because I did just move in, but my overzealous father-in-law swapped these outlets when I wasn't around. So potentially they were working before he got to them hahaha

Comment: Did your father-in-law break off the tabs on the new outlets?  It appears the old outlet tabs are broken off on the hot side.

Comment: He didn't break the hot tab. I also have a sneaking suspicion that, if this was half switched before, one of these 12-2 cables is using the neutral as a second hot wire. I'll check it out in the morning, but it's starting to make sense what happened

Comment: Can you provide clearer shots of the insides of the boxes involved please?